# Datatables not populating with data from RestAPI call

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

when trying to read back my api into data tables im getting an error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

my table is as follows:

```
 <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class=" row d-flex justify-content-center ">


            <!-- Table -->

            <table id="movieTable" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Year</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="list-list">

                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

And my script is as follows:

```
<script>
        $('#movieTable').DataTable({

            "ajax": "http://kmoffett07.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/serverSide/buildapi.php?id=1",
            dataSrc: "",
            "columns": [

                {
                    "data": "Title"
                }, {
                    "data": "Year"
                },
            ]
        });
    </script>
```

I can't see exactly what I'm doing wrong, any help appreciated!

Edit, after the advice given I've edit my script to be the following:

```
<script>
        $('#movieTable').dataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: "http://kmoffett07.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/serverSide/buildapi.php?id=2",
                dataSrc: "tv_shows",
                "columns": [

                    {
                        "Title": "Title"
                    }, {
                        "Year": "Year"
                    },
                ]

            },
        });
    </script>
```

My JSON response is as follows:

```
{
    "status": "true",
    "message": "Customer Details",
    "tv_shows": {
        "id": "456",
        "Title": "Vampire Knight",
        "Year": "2008",
        "Age": "16+",
        "IMDb": "7.5",
        "RottenTomatoes": "",
        "Netflix": "1",
        "Hulu": "1",
        "Prime": "0",
        "Disney": "0"
    }
}
```

I think my api might be the problem, i've set it to return values based on the ID queried. if i don't add ?id='x' my response is as follows:

```
{
    "status": "false",
    "message": "No customer(s) found!"
}
```

The code used to build my api is:

```
//return JSON by id
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!="") {
     
     $id = $_GET['id'];
     $query = "SELECT * FROM tv_shows WHERE id={$id}";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
     
     $tableData['id'] = $row['id'];
     $tableData['Title'] = $row['Title'];
     $tableData['Year'] = $row['Year'];
     $tableData['Age'] = $row['Age'];
     $tableData['IMDb'] = $row['IMDb'];
     $tableData['RottenTomatoes'] = $row['RottenTomatoes'];
     $tableData['Netflix'] = $row['Netflix'];
     $tableData['Hulu'] = $row['Hulu'];
     $tableData['Prime'] = $row['Prime'];
     $tableData['Disney'] = $row['Disney'];
    
    
     
     $response["status"] = "true";
     $response["message"] = "Customer Details";
     $response["tv_shows"] = $tableData;
     
    } else {
     $response["status"] = "false";
     $response["message"] = "No customer(s) found!";
    }
    echo json_encode($response); exit;
```

Updated api code to return a collection of objects rather than just one

JSon resposne as follows:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Title": "Breaking Bad",
            "Year": "2008",
            "Age": "18+",
            "IMDb": "9.5",
            "Rotten Tomatoes": "96%",
            "Netflix": "1",
            "Prime": "0",
            "Hulu": "0",
            "Disney": "0"
        },
        {
            "Title": "Stranger Things",
            "Year": "2016",
            "Age": "16+",
            "IMDb": "8.8",
            "Rotten Tomatoes": "93%",
            "Netflix": "1",
            "Prime": "0",
            "Hulu": "0",
            "Disney": "0"
        },
```

Datatables script is:

```
 <script>
      
      $('#movieTable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "order": [],
    "ajax": {
        "url": "http://kmoffett07.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/serverSide/buildapi2.php",
        "type": 'get',
        "dataType": 'json'
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "Title" },
        { "data": "Year" },
        
    ]
});
    
    </script>
```

Still no data in the datatables!

Comment: Your response doesn't support datatable server side attributes

Comment: The `dataSrc` option needs to be part of an `ajax` section. This means you need to re-structure things a bit - see [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) for an example. Right now, your `dataSrc` option is being ignored, because of where it is placed.

Comment: Also, by setting `dataSrc` to an empty string, you are saying that the row data array in your JSON is not named. Is that actually the case? You can [edit] the question to show us some sample JSON (and to show us the overall structure), if you still have an issue.

Comment: Appreciate the advice, I corrected dataSRC and provided a sample of the JSON. I'm not getting any errors now but my table still isn't populating

Comment: Thank you for the updates. Notes: (1) The `ajax` option should only contain `url` and `dataSrc`. You need to move `columns` up 1 level, so it is after the `ajax` section. (2) Is that the entire JSON, or just a part representing 1 row? If it's the entire JSON, then it will not work - there is no array `[...]` for DataTables to iterate over (one table row per item in the array). If it's just one example row object from a larger structure, then we would need to see the overall structure of the JSON. Don't need to see every row - just the overall structure.

Comment: Thank you for the help and your time! I've updated again, as you said it wont work due to my api. I've set my api to return data based on the id im querying, so if i dont put ?id='x' on the end of my api url i wont get anything returned. I added the code i used to build the api might explain it better

Comment: OK - understood. You could force your one object to be inside an array `[ {...} ]` - and then DataTables can display it - but that would be a table which only ever contains 1 record. As you note, if you change the API to return a collection (array) of objects - that would be more appropriate.

Comment: By the way - if you want to ping a commenter, you need to type `@` followed by their user name: @andrewjames. I just happened to notice your comment by chance.

Comment: @andrewjames i updated the api and its returning a collection now, still cant get my datatables populating though?!

Comment: OK - that new JSON structure looks good. You get no data - but what happens? Do you get any errors in the browser's console? (F12 to open)

Comment: Also, I see you have added `serverSide: true` to your datatable. That means the server needs to provide [additional fields](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) as well as the `data` array in its response. See the example [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data).

Comment: @andrewjames  got it working, was playing around for ages and id checked documentation everything was perfect. I then tried to update my table names in the html and noticed they didnt update. Basically i think chrome was laoding the page from a cache and not the new file i'd uploaded. Working perfect now, appreciate all your help! I've added my working code

Answer (score 1):

Got it working thanks to @andrewjames for his help!

I had to change my api to output an array of objects rather than one object and ensure JSON output matched the output defined in datatables documentation.

Working JS code:

```
 <script>
      
      
            $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#movieTable').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": "http://kmoffett07.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/serverSide/buildapi2.php",
            
            "dataSrc": "data"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "Title" },
            { "data": "Year" },
            { "data": "Age" },
            { "data": "IMDb" },
            { "data": "Rotten Tomatoes" },
            
        ]
    } );
} );


    </script>
```

HTML table structure:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column min-vh-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class=" row d-flex justify-content-center ">


            <!-- Table -->

            <table id="movieTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>IMDb</th>
                <th>Rotten Tomatoes</th>
                
                
        
            </tr>
        </thead>
      
    </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```